# How can I set the default Reminders list on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, reminders

I'm using Mountain Lion and defined a service to add a reminder. My problem: It adds it in the wrong Reminders list. I can find a preference anywhere to set the default Reminders list - Reminders (doesn't have preferences), Calendar, System Preferences. I must have set it under Lion to one list, but now I want to changed it.

The [most common suggestion was that it's the list at the top of the "list list"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4180735?start=0&tstart=0) - but that doesn't work for me.

So how do I change the default Reminders list in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I defined the Reminders list in the Automator service myself, so I could change it there. Stupid me!